# I want to get values from table Dynamically filtering the date by class

Tags: sql, dynamic

```
DECLARE @H_TS MONEY
DECLARE @CLASS VARCHAR(50)='CLASS 04'   
DECLARE @TAB_NA VARCHAR(1000)='Classdata'
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @H_TS=SUM(CAST([HISTORY TOTAL$] AS MONEY)) FROM '+@TAB_NA+' WHERE SUBCLASS!=''TOTAL'' AND CLASS LIKE '+@CLASS+''
  EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@H_TS nvarchar(200) OUTPUT', @H_TS = @H_TS OUTPUT
PRINT @H_TS
```

I am getting below error

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '04'.

Because my variable class contain space  is there any way to solve this with out changing class  value (not removeing space in class)

Answer (score 1):

I think you were just missing a couple of single quote marks:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT @H_TS=SUM(CAST([HISTORY TOTAL$] AS MONEY)) FROM '+@TAB_NA+' 
WHERE SUBCLASS!=''TOTAL'' AND CLASS LIKE ''' + @CLASS + '''' 

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@H_TS nvarchar(200) OUTPUT', @H_TS = @H_TS OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to do a LIKE query and need your % operator, this might be what you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE ClassData ([History Total$] int, SUBCLASS varchar(100), class varchar(100));

INSERT INTO ClassData VALUES (1, 'TOTAL', '1Class 04');
INSERT INTO ClassData VALUES (2, 'NOTTOTAL', '1Class 04 22');

DECLARE @H_TS MONEY
DECLARE @CLASS VARCHAR(50)='CLASS 04'   
DECLARE @TAB_NA VARCHAR(1000)='Classdata'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @H_TS=SUM(CAST([HISTORY TOTAL$] AS MONEY)) FROM '+@TAB_NA+' WHERE SUBCLASS!=''TOTAL'' AND CLASS LIKE ''%' + @CLASS + '%''';

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@H_TS nvarchar(200) OUTPUT', @H_TS = @H_TS OUTPUT
SELECT @H_TS

DROP TABLE ClassData
```

Good luck.